# How can CreateFile fail with FILE_SHARE_READ and succeed with FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, process

Try it yourself:

Create an XLS file, open it in Excel.

Open sysinternals Process Monitor, and watch what happens while you make a copy of your XLS file in the explorer (just hit ctrl-c ctrl-v).

Two calls to `::CreateProcess` in a row. First call asks for read permissions, and gets Access denied. Second call asks for read plus write plus delete and passes.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you open a file with `FILE_SHARE_READ` you're saying you're willing to share access to this file, but only for reads.

If you open with all the flags, you're willing to share access also for writes/delete.

`FILE_SHARE_READ` is more restrictive than `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE`

If some other process (excel) has this file opened for e.g. write (and it has the sharing flags set), the only way you can access it is to accept sharing it for write.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use compatible sharing modes.  If Excel opens the file with FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE then subsequent attempts to open the file must use at least those same flags.  Specifically from the [MSDN documentation on CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx):

> You cannot request a sharing mode that conflicts with the access mode that is specified in an existing request that has an open handle. CreateFile would fail and the GetLastError function would return ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.